# Custom Customer Attribute not Saving Magento 2

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes

I have used the following script to add a custom customer attribute.

```
<?php

namespace Harrigo\ContractPricing\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface {
protected $customerSetupFactory;
private $attributeSetFactory;

public function __construct(CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory, AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory) {
    $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
}

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context) {

        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'cp_permissions', [
            'type' => 'static',
            'label' => 'Account Type',
            'input' => 'select',
            'source' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table::class,
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => false,
            'sort_order' => 101,
            'position' => 101,
            'system' => false,
            'adminhtml_only' => true,
            'option'         => ['values' => ['Master', 'Branch']]
        ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'cp_permissions')
            ->addData([
                'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer'],
            ]);

        $attribute->save();

        }
    }
```

The attribute after some difficulty now shows on the form however no longer saved. Initially the attribute didn't show until i set the `source` differently and set **user_defined** to false. I originally changed these in database and all worked however now that i've got the installer script almost working (attribute shows and source was set within database) i have noticed that values are not saving.

I have checked and `system` value is set to 0 / false in `customer_eav_attribute` table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change attribute `type` to `varchar` instead of `static`, and try again.

**Add Attribute:**

```
$customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'cp_permissions', [
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'label' => 'Account Type',
        'input' => 'select',
        'source' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table::class,
        'required' => false,
        'visible' => true,
        'user_defined' => false,
        'sort_order' => 101,
        'position' => 101,
        'system' => false,
        'adminhtml_only' => true,
        'option' =>
            array (
                'values' =>
                    array (
                        0 => 'Master',
                        1 => 'Branch'
                    )
            )
    ]);
```

Comment: yeah tried that still no luck

Comment: Seems to be working again not sure if this fixed it but thanks!